# Web Driver version compatibility for IEDriverServer

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Web Driver version 2.21.1.0 and IEDriverServer version 2.25.2.0 . This works fine in IE browser. Now, I need to know the compatibility of the Web driver 2.21.1.0. Whether it will support the IEDriverServer version 2.32.3.0 and what are the driver version it will support.

I have tried searching regarding this in many links but couldn't able to find the correct compatibility for the mentioned Web Driver version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Check the below link.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG

**Webdriver v2.22.0**

```
IE driver now uses the IEDriverServer. You may need to download
this. Set the "useLegacyInternalServer" to boolean true if you
need the old behaviour.
```

Comment: Link is now dead.